# Permission denied (publickey) but the server is not using public key authentication

Tags: permissions, ssh, authentication

I just accidentally used `ssh-keygen -R  (ip address)` but later i found the server authentication is not based on the public key authentication but just password authentication.

now when i type `ssh root@ ip address`, the server responded with `Permission denied (publickey).`

how would I return to the password authentcation

Comment: You've not provided OS/release details; and mention `root@` which is *disabled* by default for on-topic OSes for this site, so being specific may help us to help you.

Comment: it is ubuntu 20.04,  P.S. I am just starting the server with root, I will disable it afterwards, thanks